# Android Studio Project Failed to complete Build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I faced with this error for the first time when building my project and I don't know how to solve it.
Can Someone help me?

[image: Build Log]

```
Build: build failed
Run build /Project/festoco
Run tasks
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
Execute taskAction: 
Cause: llvm-rs-cc is missing



java.lang.IllegalStateException: llvm-rs-cc is missing
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.compileAllRenderscriptFiles(AndroidBuilder.java:1194)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile.taskAction(RenderscriptCompile.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:788)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:755)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at ...
```

Comment: do you try to clean your project and then build it again?

Comment: @amir133 No, I didn't. Thanks for tip! Let me Try this.\

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps -

1. Navigate to Home/User/Android/Sdk/build-tools.
2. Delete all the folders from there.
3. Go to SDK Manager and download the latest version of Android SDK build-tools.

Answer (score 0):

This error "llvm-rs-cc" is missing :  related to Android SDK "build-tools" folder, downloaded build tools will be inside this also in any build version folder like 28.0.3 there is a file with this name  "llvm-rs-cc" if  your android SDK path in not pointing to the right place and compiler couldn't find it this error will happen.

to Solve:
1- Change the Android Sdk path to the right location
or
2- Delete related build folder inside "build-tools" (for example if in build.gradle :     buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' you must delete the folder with the name of 28.0.3 ) and open "SDK Manager" and download related sdk.
3 - Change buildToolsVersion in gradle to another downloaded version